# Write to php Page while other reading the page

Tags: php

i want to update the content of myPage.PHP page by writing new **String**  to this page   my question is there is any problem if i will update the content of **myPage.php** file by writing  new string to this file   while may there are thousands of visitors visit this page **myPage.php**?

please note : only me will write to this page , no others will write to this page , may be every 30 minutes or hour.

Comment: You are going to give specific examples of what you are doing.

Comment: Do you just mean to manually update the page (by SFTP or whatever) while the site is live?

Comment: the visitors will read some text string from myPage.php by using ajax , may i will update myPage.PHP while visitors reading string text from this page by ajax .

Comment: The old version of the file will stay there (and will be viewed/read by the users) until the new version is saved to the disk.

Comment: this is mean no need to use lock and unlock file??

Comment: please note : i will update my page content programmaticly by open the PHP file , then write some string , and finally close file , every thing programmtaly

Answer (score 0):

Once the page is loaded in the browser no longer changes ( except if you are called AJAX or similar ) . So even if you delete or edit the file there are no problems as long as your users will not update the page .

Comment: the visitors will read some text string from myPage.php by using ajax .

Comment: When you update the file (save) users begin to see your changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can create exactly the same page with a different name
example: myPage2.php and you can write a new String there without any problem because your visitors will be in the original page myPage.php